# Strcmp return value not correct?

Tags: c, strcmp

This is driving me crazy, I've done several tests in a similar fashion in a test program in just the main function and everything works as expected, but when comparing these answers in a quiz program I am writing I am always receiving a return value of -1 even when the string appear to be equal!

```
void TraverseList(LinkedList *inList)
{
    int compareTest;
    char userAnswer[64];
    char string1[64];
    char string2[64];

    for (inList->curr = inList-> head; inList->curr != NULL; inList->curr = inList->curr->next)
    {
        printf("%s", inList->curr->stringQuestion);
        scanf("%s", userAnswer);

        strcpy(string1, userAnswer);
        strcpy(string2, inList->curr->stringAnswer);

        compareTest = strcmp(string1, string2);

        printf("%s\n", string1);
        printf("%s\n", string2);
        printf("Return value of strcmp: %d\n", compareTest);


        if(compareTest == 0)
        {
            printf("Correct!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Incorrect!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Example output right now:

```
How many hours are in a day? 24
24 // this is string1
24 // this is string2

Return value of strcmp: -1
Incorrect!
```

Comment: What do `strlen(string1)` and `strlen(string2)` return?

Comment: Try `printf("|%s|\n", string2);`. I'll bet there's an extra space in the answer.

Comment: string1 returns 2, string2 returns 3. I'm guessing that is the problem.

Comment: Bingo, that's the problem. `string2` has an extra character, probably a space at the end.

Comment: A few minutes in the debugger probably would have told you the same thing.

Comment: Wow thank you for the heads up. When I created my nodes storing the answers I had "24\n" for example. Removed the \n and I am working perfectly fine. Thank you so much...

Comment: regarding this line: 'scanf("%s", userAnswer);' 1) the code should always check the returned value from scanf() and family of functions, to assure the input/conversion was successful.   2) the format string should have a leading ' ' (space) so any white space is skipped over.  3) the format specifier '%s' should have a length modifier so as to avoid any buffer overrun problems.  4) always pre-clear the input buffer to '\0' so there will always be a trailing NUL byte so strcpy, etc will work correctly.  On several implementations, scanf does not append a trailing '\0'

Comment: @user3413540 whenever reading input, whether from `scanf`, `fgets` or `getline`, you must be aware that they will all include the `newline` with the string they read. With `scanf` you can use `"%[^\n]%*c"` as the format specifier to prevent reading the `newline` into the string while at the same time **reading and discarding** the newline to prevent it from remaining in the input buffer (`stdin`). With `fgets` or `getline`, you simply overwrite the `newline` with a `null-terminating` character. (e.g. `line[strlen (line) - 1] = 0;`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `scanf` `%s` just reads a single word, it doesn't include the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

When you are concerned that you are not getting the proper results when using strings, it's a good habit to place some identifying marker around the printout of the variable.

```
printf("X%sX\n", variable);
```

This will show you what the computer is really testing.

Also, if you find this doesn't work for you, you can try and print out the individual characters from the string with their ascii values, in case there are hidden ones like '\a'.

```
for(x=0; x<strlen(string_variable); x++)
    printf("'%c' = %d\n", string_variable[x], string_variable[x]);
```

Comment: This usually works, unless the string happens to contain certain unprintable characters (which I've had happen). Using `strlen` is usually the quickest test to check if the string has all the characters you expect.

Comment: @nneonneo : True, but this method will tell you what the rogue character is, and can make it easier to track down where the error is.

Comment: It's often much more efficient to just learn how to use a debugger to print hex values than it is to constantly be writing complicated printf statements everywhere. There's no reason to avoid printf, it's quite useful, but it's not always the best tool for the job.